# Spells which can pull a hero out of Chronosphere

Tags: dota

What are the spells which can pull heroes out of Chronosphere?

Pudge's hook can pull,
What about Eath Spirit's Geomagnetic Grips, Force staffs, Vengi's Swap, Thrall's Glimpse, Kunkka's X Mark. I Can just remember only these. There can be more.

Comment: Wisp tethered relocate and Tusk snowball could be possible, haven't tested though. Also keeper of the light/chen teleports?

Comment: @Hex Can we pass inside the chrono with snowball?

Comment: no, if you snowball into the sphere you will get stuck. But if you're standing close to the edge and snowball away from the sphere you may be able to save an ally who is inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only spells that force a hero deplacement can push someone out of chronosphere. After having tested (On DotA 2) :

**You can use :**

- Vengeful spirit's Swap
- Hook from Pudge
- Fissure from Earthsaker (if well placed and the hero is on the extreme limit of Chronosphere)
- Blinding light and Recall from Keeper of the Light
- Glimpse from Disruptor
- X marks the spot from Kunkka
- Beastmaster's Roar can push someone out if it's not the primary target
- Wisp can Relocate someone out
- Chen's test of faith
- Enigma's Black hole can pull you out (but you end up in blackhole anyway)
- Morphling's Adaptive strike can push you out
- Storm Spirit's electric vortex
- Rubick's Telekinesis someone out
- Darkseer vaccum works
- Elder Titan's Earth splitter works too (if the enemy is enough on the edge of the Chrono)
- Magnus : either Skewer or Reverse Polarity
- Chaos Knight's Reality Rift
- Tiny Toss : if the target is on the edge of chronosphere you can toss the unit (allied or enemy) to another unit out of the chrono
- Batrider's flamebreak
- Spirit Breaker with Nether Strike and level(s) in bash (otherwise He just gets stuck with the target in the Chrono). You can achieve it with charge of darkness or regular bash too however it requires a perfect positionning
- Invoker's Deafening Blast
- Cogs someone out (I thought it was a fixed bug however it seems to work)
- Earth Spirit's Geomagnetic Grip (to pull an ally out) or Boulder Smash (to kick a unit out if located on the edge of the chrono)

**You can't**

- Forcestaff somone out (for the obvious reason that the Faceless Void would become the Useless Void)
- Tusk's snowball : will roll through the chronosphere not taking anyone

**edit : added Earth Spirit's skills to the list**

Comment: nice work bro :)

Comment: @WizLiz you can test everything by yourself pretty easily. http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=22468 ... Just do -createhero axe enemy , -wtf for no cooldowns/mana costs, and plenty of others.

Comment: @WizLiz For original dota it will be tougher, but the mechanics at play should be the same (or it's a reportable bug).

Comment: Okay, I Finished testing ;) @Decency Thanks for the command list, this was really helpfull