# How can I escape Bloodseeker's Rupture?

Tags: dota-2

I would like to ask this question as I've been suffering quite badly from Bloodseeker's ultimate, Rupture recently.

So I would like to ask, what is considered "movement" in Dota 2? So far, I know that Phoenix's Icarus Dive is considered movement and would take rupture damage.

Another follow up question is, how do you escape without triggering the rupture damage from bloodseeker?

Comment: In early game BS often needs to silence himself to do more damage. Always carry a Town Portal Scroll with you. :)

Comment: So town portal scroll is not considered movement? that's nice to know, now I can escape certain death in some situation.

Comment: @Trollwut not anymore

Comment: @Trollwut Bloodseeker no longer silences himself at all as of 6.84 (September 2014)

Comment: Now I'm officially an oldfag. :C

Comment: Although the other part of @Trollwut's comment isn't correct anymore, you should always carry a TP scroll in Dota 2. If you happen to have just enough gold to buy an item you want, sure, go ahead and buy it, but the first thing you should do afterwards is buy a TP at a side shop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that makes your hero move from its previous location is concidered as a movement. **e.g.**  A secondary target to Beastmaster's Roar is pushed back and this is concidered a movement that would induce a HP loss from Rupture. ([Here's a list of skills that force another hero to move (even very slightly)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131383/24592))

In order to not take damage you basically have to break the 1300 distance limit in 0.25sec (or less). That means that technically moving at 5201+ movespeed would allow you to take no Rupture Damage while running.

Getting a full list of what would allow you to escape Rupture damage is not really interesting and woud likely change overtime. However you can safely assume that any form of Global TP (Wisp, Furion, Kepper of the Light's Recall, Town Portal Scroll etc.) is ok to use. It is otherwise very hard to break that limit of 1300 distance per 0.25sec.

Some exceptions to that are :

- Queen of Pain which has a blink with 1300 range => by blinking and moving right away you won't take Rupture Damage. That's the only blink in the game with enough range to achieve that trick.
- Clockwerk with HookShot level 3 (6000ms)
- Storm's Ball Lightning (which makes him invulnerable)
- Ember Spririt can join a remnnant (invulnerable while joining)
- Puck can Orb out (since the Orb has a max range of 1800 and is joined instantly).

You can take a quick look at *[How to break the 522ms barrier in Dota 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191672/24592)*.

Comment: Ok, this was what I was looking for, thx

Comment: Ember Spirit can ult without taking Rupture damage

Comment: Can Puck jaunt out?  Does a blink dagger work?  I seem to remember blink dagger not damaging while the blink *abilities* did...

Answer (score 1):

> If the target moves more than 1300 distance in 0.25 seconds, it will not take any damage.
>   Blocked by Linken's Sphere.

So basicly any type of movement exept things like Portal Scroll,IO-Ult Furion-TP. Euls also help to get some time.

Comment: Except that glimpse work with rupture even though you're not moving

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to escape in order to not die from Rupture, you should generally be altering your whole play strategy when there is a BS on the enemy team, just like if there were a Riki or a Techies - you simply can't play the game "as normal" and expect to get away with it.

The first thing is to carry a TP scroll. If you do get caught, especially early game, you can often just TP away before he has time to kill you.

Next, you should be on the look out and be aware to when you're vulnerable to a rupture and when you're likely to have one cast on you. Don't wander around with low health, along in the jungle as this will make you an easy target. Try to keep some health and try to stay with your team to avoid getting caught alone. If you can't see BS on the map then assume he's nearby.

If it makes sense on your current hero, buy a Eul's Scepter. It can buy you time either to use it on yourself and make yourself temporarily untargetable, or use on BS and give yourself time to TP away or get your team to come and help you.

Again if it makes sense, build a Pipe of Insight to mitigate some of the damage.

Answer (score 1):

Buy linkens would a choice ..... it helps a lot against rupture and duel also ...

Comment: Not really that great of a choice as Bloodseeker can easily pop linkens with his 'Q' ability.